# Async Controllers or Ajax?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am writing an Asp.Net MVC 4 app, in which, once the user logs in, they are redirected to a dashboard page where i have these 4 seperate divs on that page. 4 different database calls have to be made to fill in these divs. I was planning to use multiple Ajax calls so that the user doesnt have to wait until all the data come back , to see the page. Then I read about async controllers and now i am confused whether to use async controllers or ajax calls for my purpose.
please help !
Thanks in advance !

Comment: you can use both async and ajax. and why dont u use web.api? knockout.js ? looks like u can benefit.

Comment: @DarthVader, I don't think async controllers will help the OP; they won't reduce waiting time for the user.

Comment: ajax calls are async anyway, having async or regular controller wont help with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynch controllers, to my mind, allow for more responsive request processing on the server by allowing it to handle mre concurrent requests in a non-blocking fashion similar to node.js.  Ajax is, as noted, asychronous by default on the client/browser and this is what you need to allow the page to render without blocking.

Comment: Just found out that using ajax will not help me with SEO.So i guess i dont have to worry about SEO when using async controllers ?

Answer (score 0):

> Then I read about async controllers and now i am confused whether to
>   use async controllers or ajax calls for my purpose

Just not to mix apples with pears.

You make an asynchronous controller to spawn another thread **on the server**, the client does not know anything about it. (to avoid thread starvation on server, it makes sense for long time operations - like binary operations etc.)

You make an asynchronous request just not the block the UI thread of the Browser **on the client**.